# Not able to access internal class using assembly.GetType() on Mac

Tags: c#, mono, system.reflection, visual-studio-mac

I have an ASP.NET framework application which runs fine on Windows. I have been trying to run it on mac using Visual Studio for Mac and mono, but have been running into this issue. The code is building properly without any errors, but when I try to run it using xsp, I am getting a NullReferenceException. On inspecting the root of the problem using the disassembler in VS, I found that this is the snippet where exception is thrown

```cs
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(RemotingConfiguration));
Type type = assembly.GetType("System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingConfigHandler");
FieldInfo field = type.GetField("_errorMode", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

I tried copying this code in another file and running it and sure enough, the debugger shows `type` to be null. On searching online, `RemoteConfigHandler` seems to be an internal class, but it should not be an issue as reflection can fetch internal classes as well when provided with a fully classified name.

Not sure if this is relevant, but I have also tried listing all the available types using

```cs
foreach (Type t in assembly.GetTypes())
{
    Console.WriteLine(t.FullName.ToString());
}
```

and this is the list I get: https://pastebin.com/3cXfc41i

I don't know if this is mono specific issue or am I missing something, please help.

Comment: Presumably this internal class doesn't exist in Mono, or if it does then it exists in another assembly. Considering it's an internal class, it's not part of the public contract so there is no reason why it should exist at all. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This code is part of an existing dll, so I don't have any control over it.

Comment: Get a new dll then, or decompile it and fix it, or suggest a bug fix to the publishers. It's relying on undocumented internals, which could break between one version and the next, never mind entirely different frameworks.

Comment: I'll try to do the suggested. Meanwhile I was looking into the mscorlib code for mono and it does contain the `RemotingConfigHandler` internal class ([Here](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/5d2e3bc3b3c8184d35b2f7801e88d96470d367c4/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/remoting/configuration.cs)). So I'm not sure where is the issue.

Comment: Unless a vendor explicitly states Mono is a supported framework, you should assume anything related to .NET Framework is Windows only. Besides, Mono/.NET remoting/ASP.NET 4.x are all legacy technologies you should migrate away from https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-mono/

Comment: The `referencesource` folder is just Mono's copy of https://referencesource.microsoft.com/. You won't find `RemotingConfigHandler` in https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/5d2e3bc3b3c8184d35b2f7801e88d96470d367c4/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Remoting nor will you find it in other frameworks such as dotnet Core https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/search?q=RemotingConfigHandler

Comment: Oh, didn't know that @Charlieface. I'm trying the disassembly route anyway, so hope that works. Thanks!